# Winkel Tripel projection in Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj

I would like to use the Winkel Tripel projection with GeoPandas 0.8.1

Consider the following example.

```
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.name != "Antarctica") & (world.name != "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands")]
world['gdp_per_cap'] = world.gdp_md_est / world.pop_est
world = world.to_crs(epsg=3395)
world.plot(column = 'gdp_per_cap')
```

This example is based on the  [GeoPandas tutorial on managing projections](https://geopandas.org/projections.html), and reprojects to Mercator.

First, I tried reprojecting to Winkel Tripel using an epsg code. However, it seems that this projection does not have such a code (i.e. I can't seem to find this projection on [EPSG.io](http://epsg.io/)).

Next, I tried looking for a list of supported epsg codes. This made me realize that this functionality in fact is handled by pyproj.

While PROJ does seem to support [Winkel Tripel](https://proj.org/operations/projections/wintri.html), I haven't figured out if and how I can get this functionality to work in this case.

I suspected that I could invoke the proj string `wintri`, but did not figure out how.

I seem to have found a mention of `wintri` in [the source code of v2.1.3](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.1.3rel/_modules/pyproj/proj.html), however I can't seem to find anything in the documentation of the current stable version.

Finally, I came across [this exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23089/defining-winkel-tripel-in-proj-4-8-0) which lead me to suspect that it is not possible to use the Winkel Tripel projection in PROJ, and by extension GeoPandas.

That thread is from 2015 and I haven't found any development regarding this.

In conclusion, am I understanding correctly that it is not possible to use the Winkel Tripel projection with GeoPandas?

Or if it is possible, what am I missing?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36898 claims that Winkel Tripel has EPSG 54042

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, this is the correct and simple way:

```py
world = world.to_crs('+proj=wintri')
world.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I did not manage to find this syntax in the documentation, did you?

Comment: This is PROJ string. One of the options listed in documentation https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/user_guide/projections.html. You can find the string itself defined here https://proj.org/operations/projections/wintri.html.

Comment: Thanks again! Indeed I came across both pieces of information but somehow did not make the connection.